# The HAL drivers are feature-oriented instead of IP-oriented. What does this mean?

Tags: stm32, embedded, arm, programming

I had bought a STM32F3 Nucleo board sometime back and today I started going through the HAL documentation for that board. It said that the HAL drivers are **"Feature-Oriented"** and not **"IP-Oriented"**. What does ***IP Oriented*** mean?

Comment: It means that someone at marketing barfed. These aren't technical terms. Also, the ST so-called "HAL" isn't a HAL, but a bunch of fairly low-level wrapper functions around "scary register access".

Comment: @Lundin I would not call the HAL as fairly low level wrapper but a fairly high level. For example, using the HAL very complex operations such as accessing registers on a I2C device can be handled with a single line of code that handles everything for you under the hood, including the peripheral and required interrupt and DMA handling if necessary. You might confuse this with LL HAL which is a low level wrapper.

Comment: @Justme A real HAL has functions like "i2c_send", "i2c_receive" etc. ST calls every single piece of code "HAL" so it's not easy to tell what part of it that "HAL" refers to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP in this context refers to hardware designs or other components that are licensed from a vendor.  Thus, "IP-oriented" means designed around the IP.  Feature oriented means designed around common features.

Essentially, they are saying that they try to make the HAL work in a way that is consistent around across different types of hardware (IP).

Answer (score 0):

IP means intellectual property, which in itself means it is patented.

It's open to interpretation, but one could guess that instead of making the HAL drivers unique through patents (spending energy into patenting bits of code), they rather make it feature-rich.

Comment: While patents are one type type of IP, not all types of intellectual property are patents.  Trade secrets such as design files or source code are also intellectual property.